# Slow ffmpeg conversion of 1080p 30FPS 4Mbps mp4 to webm

Tags: ffmpeg

On Ubuntu 20.04 with 4 cores and 8GB of RAM (So I feel that the tech specs are high enough), in ffmpeg I'm running the following command to convert a 1080p 30FPS 4Mbps mp4 to webm but it only converts at a speed of about 0.125 (about 5 FPS, 2.5kbps). The video is 10 minutes long, so this means it is taking over an hour to covert. For the use-case I'm building this for I need to speed this up, are there any options I can add in with ffmpeg?

```
ffmpeg -i /home/test/game1080-4MBPS.mp4 /home/test/game1080-4MBPS.webm
```

Comment: 4 CPUs… you mean 1 CPU, 4 cores? I rather doubt anyone's going to build a 4CPU machine & put only 8GB RAM in it. Knowing precisely what CPU it is might help, but tbh it sounds like you're just going to have to lower your expectations.

Comment: Yes, you are right @Tetsujin, thanks for the clarification!  1 CPU, 4 cores.